# Pickled Pandas Dataframes differ without changes in the data

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have noticed that when I pickle a pandas dataframe, the file differs each time even if there are no changes in the data.

This is annoying as I am making minor changes in the code that produces the dataframe and want to check that the result does not change.

Each time I find that the files differ; however, when I read both pickle files into memory then `old_dataframe.equals(new_dataframe)` returns `True`.

This does not happen with numpy arrays; the pickled files do not change when the data do not change.

Is there any way to make sure this does not happen: if dataframes are identical, make sure their pickled files are identical too?

Comment: Do you get deterministic behavior if you set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` variable to `0`?  By default, hash values for strings in Python are randomized as a security measure, which conceivably may influence the pickling process for dataframes.  Just speculation on my part.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985294/is-the-pickling-process-deterministic

Comment: @NicholasM Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, it does not help.  cmp mentions the first difference, and in this case it is byte 4, line 1.  This means that they differ in the fourth byte.  So this is probably some kind of a header.  (Earlier, the line number was larger.)